# ef core set the same value object to multiple entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm using EF Core 3.1 with CosmosDB and trying to implements some DDD approaches.
I have Customer entity

```
public class Customer : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    // For EF Core
    protected Customer()
    {
    }

    public Customer(Guid id, string name, Address address)
    {
        CustomerId = id;
        Name = name;
        SetAddress(address);
    }

    public Guid CustomerId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public Address Address { get; private set; }

    public void SetAddress(Address address)
    {
        Address = address ?? throw new ValidationException(nameof(Address), "Required");
    }
}
```

and Address as a value object:

```
public class Address
{
    // For EF Core
    public Address()
    {
    }

    public Address(string street, string city, string state, string country)
    {
        Street = street;
        City = city;
        State = state;
        Country = country;
    }

    public string Street { get; private set; }
    public string City { get; private set; }
    public string State { get; private set; }
    public string Country { get; private set; }
}
```

Entity configuration is:

```
builder.ToContainer("Customers");
builder.HasNoDiscriminator();
builder.HasKey(x => x.CustomerId);    
builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Address);
```

I need to get a list of customers from database and then update address for them.

```
var customers = await _repository.GetAll(x => x.Name == "Joe", cancellationToken);
var address = new Address("St1", "London", "", "UK");
foreach (var customer in customers)
{
   customer.SetAddress(address);
   _repository.Update(customer);
}
await _repository.Save(cancellationToken);
```

Let's say I have only 2 items in `customers`. After `Save` I will got `null` for the first item, and the ne address for the second one. Cannot figured out why. But when I create a new address for every item in the loop, then everything works fine

```
foreach (var customer in customers)
{
   customer.SetAddress(new Address("St1", "London", "", "UK"););
   _repository.Update(customer);
}
```

Could you please suggest why should I create a new object every time?

Comment: Why you have a key you only have one entry per key : builder.HasKey(x => x.CustomerId);

Comment: What do you mean? It is like primary key for every customer. It is not a partition key, so, I think it's not an issue in this case

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because EF Core tracks class instances.

In the 1st iteration you put address into the 1st customer and EF Core starts to track it. And when you put it to the 2nd customer EF Core recognizes it as a move the same address from one customer to another.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any solution?

Comment: Just create a new instance.

Comment: maybe I can somehow disable tracking? What if the list contains 1000 items? It will create a 1000 the same objects

Comment: If you disable tracking ef core won't be able to understand whether your entity is changed. What's inside your `_repository.Update(customer);`?

Comment: _context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;